# Eslint - No empty first and last lines for function bodies

Tags: javascript, eslint

Which rule is used for converting this code

```
function sayHello() {

   console.log("Hello world!");

}
```

into

```
function sayHello() {
   console.log("Hello world!"); // No empty lines at the end and beginning
}
```

?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/#layout-formatting is a nice section of the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a rule for blocks: [`padded-blocks`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks).

If enabled, an option is:

> "blocks" require or disallow padding within block statements, function bodies, and class static blocks

There doesn't look to be a configurable option for functions in particular.

You'll want the config option:

```
[2, 'never']
```

or

```
[2, { blocks: 'never' }]
```